# Can people hear the music I'm listening in a Skype video call?

Tags: skype

I was on a video call today on Skype with my headphones. I started to listen to music on Youtube with my headphones in middle of the call. Can other people in the call have heard the music was listening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the sound is audible in the room, yes, they can hear it. Your microphone picks it up.  I hear this from others in Skype and Zoom meetings.

If the sound is truly inaudible, then no, they cannot hear it. There is no cross-connection between outside and separate inside sounds in the computer.

Answer (score 3):

Can you hear the music with the headphones off? If you can't hear the music with the headphones off, your computer's mic can't hear it. If you're blasting the music into the room out of your computer speakers, then your computer mic will pick it up and the people on the other end of the Skype call will hear it.

Comment: Yes.  Very loud sounds creeping out into the air can be heard.  So such my word "truly inaudible"  :)

Comment: Oh yes, good point.

Comment: Though while they are wearing the headphones, the mic will most probably not be able to pick the noise up.